# What's the point of having an SPF record with a final ~all rule?

Tags: email, postfix-mta, spf

Over the past hour, I've been digging into SPF, skimming through [RFC-4408](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4408.txt), and going over [another tutorial](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/spf.html).

I own my own domain, with postfix installed on the server behind that domain. Apart from my normal address, I want to also be able to send e-mails using GMail using my own e-mail address as sender.

I do receive quite a lot of bounce-back-spam where spammers have used my e-mail address as "From" line :( From what I understand, SPF is used to check whether a given SMTP server is allowed to send mails with certain sender domain names. Which would help with said bounce-back.

So clearly, If I want to be able to send mails via gmail, I have to allow gmail to send in my name via the SPF record.

Following [their help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en), I added the following TXT record:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

They *specifically* advise against using `-all` as fallthrough rule.

Given that `~all` is a "soft fail" which still accepts all messages, **what's the point of enabling SPF at all?**

I tried to send some mails from an external host and they were accepted with the only difference being that my mail-server assumes that there was no SPF record.

Excerpt from the logs when sending via GMail:

```
May  8 15:15:58 h2150855 policyd-spf[6184]: None; identity=helo; client-ip=300.300.300.300; helo=mail-lf0-f52.google.com; envelope-from=mygmailaddress@gmail.com; receiver=mypersonaladdress@example.com
May  8 15:15:58 h2150855 policyd-spf[6184]: Pass; identity=mailfrom; client-ip=300.300.300.300; helo=mail-lf0-f52.google.com; envelope-from=mygmailaddress@gmail.com; receiver=mypersonaladdress@example.com
```

... and sending via a third-party server:

```
May  8 15:19:17 h2150855 policyd-spf[6554]: None; identity=helo; client-ip=301.300.300.300; helo=theserver.example.com; envelope-from=exhuma@theserver.example.com; receiver=mypersonaladdress@example.com
May  8 15:19:17 h2150855 policyd-spf[6554]: None; identity=mailfrom; client-ip=301.300.300.300; helo=theserver.example.com; envelope-from=exhuma@theserver.example.com; receiver=mypersonaladdress@example.com
```

The only difference I can see is that the postfix SPF plugin marks the gmail message explicitly as `Pass`, while the other is marked as `None`.

I am now at the point where I think that adding SPF did not really do anything to my mail-setup and am considering removing it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it recommends `~all` over `-all` is because of the way it interacts with DMARC; The recommendation to use `-all` pre-dates the existence of DMARC. `-all` is indeed an effective (and correct) setting *if you are using SPF alone*, but `-all` will usually break DMARC because its rules will not be evaluated. If you set a `~all` default SPF action, it hands-off the decision to the DMARC layer, at which point you can say "we consider SPF softfail to be a hardfail", and go on to reap the other benefits of DMARC.

So, in short `~all` is not pointless *if you're using DMARC*. (`?all` is **always** pointless!)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use ~all only for testing and use -all for production. Even the RFC recommends that:

> If domain owners choose to publish SPF records, it is RECOMMENDED
>   that they end in "-all", or redirect to other records that do, so
>   that a definitive determination of authorization can be made.

Some sites will actually reject the e-mail, or direct it to a spam folder, when encountering a soft-fail, but simply forcing a hard fail will improve changes of sites rejecting messages which try to forge your domain as the sender.

Comment: Rejecting on a softfail is a direct RFC contravention and IME is actually very rare. The RFC recommendation predates the existence of DMARC, which is broken by the presence of `-all`, so you should use `~all` if you're also using DMARC, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`~all` is interpreted in some DMARC packages like OpenDMARC as fail by default, although you can change a flag so that it's interpreted as pass.

Similarly, `?all` is interpreted in OpenDMARC as fail by default.

In contrast, `-all` is always interpreted as fail, regardless of your DMARC package deployed.

I've written a post that covers this topic: [Why SPF Authentication Fails](https://dmarcly.com/blog/why-spf-authentication-fails-none-neutral-fail-hard-fail-soft-fail-temperror-and-permerror-explained).

It also covers other related concepts including none, neutral, temperror, permerror, etc.